# C# 2DArray IndexOutOfBound, Why?

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

In the following C# code I want to create a 2D Array with the size of [5,2].
If I understand it correctly, that should look like this:

0     1     2

0[0,0] [0,1] [0,2]

1[1,0] [1,1] [1,2]

2[2,0] [2,1] [2,2]

3[3,0] [3,1] [3,2]

4[4,0] [4,1] [4,2]

But why does my program throw out an

> IndexOutOfRangeException

...?

```
using System;

namespace program {
    
    class program{
        Random random = new Random();
        
        int[,] board = new int[5,2];
        
        public program(){
            
            Print2DArray(randomBoard(0.5,board));
            
        }
        
        public int[,] randomBoard(double chance, int[,] board){
            int[,] temp = board;
            
            for(int y = 0; y < board.GetLength(1); y++){
                for(int x = 0; x < board.GetLength(0); x++){
                    
                    if(random.NextDouble() <= chance){
                        
                        board[y,x] = 1;
                        
                    } else {
                        
                        board[y,x] = 0;
                        
                    }               
                }
            }
            
            return temp;
        }
        
          public static void Print2DArray<T>(T[,] matrix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(matrix[i,j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
        
        static void Main(string[] args){    
            program program1 = new program();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: it is index out of bounds because the array starts at 0 and ends at 4, this = 5 indexs, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, if you want to keep the same code then make it 6, and same goes for the 2d part

Comment: Sorry, i explained poorly, I edited it now. In my program I used < array.GetLength(0) / < array.GetLength(1) , so it wouldn't really matter, the problem is still there

Comment: My bad, i didnt try the code out until just then. il lhave another look

Comment: is it not just because the for loops are the wrong way around? now that i actually look at it in visual studio

Comment: `y` should go to `board.GetLength(0)` instead of `GetLength(1)`. And similarly, `x` uses the wrong bounds, too.

Comment: thanks! guess i confused these two.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `y` goes from `0` to number of elements in dimension **`1`**
while `x` goes `0` to number of elements in dimension **`0`**

However, inside your `for` loop you seem to have the dimensions swapped,

> board[y,x] = 1; // change this to    board [x,y] = 1;

similarly for the `else` condition it should be board[x,y] = 0

Comment: Thanks! Guess i confused these two.